# searching/extracting specific word not the complete line in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to search a word in a file in Unix that should return only the word not the complete line.

For ex:

Sample.text:

```
Hello abc hi aeabcft 123abc OK
```

Expected output:
   abc
   aeabcft
   123abc

If I search abc in file Sample.txt using grep, it will return complete line but I want the words that contains abc

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -Eo` with an enhanced regex to search all matching words

```
grep -Eo '\b[[:alnum:]]*abc[[:alnum:]]*\b' Sample.text
abc
aeabcft
123abc
```

As per `man grep`:

> `-o, --only-matching`
>        `Prints only the matching part of the lines.`

Comment: Hi Anubhav, thanks for the response. Updated my question to make it more clear. Can you help better

Answer (score 1):

If you need to also do other processing to the file that `grep` can't accomplish, you could use Awk for printing only the regex match on the line.

```
awk -v r="abc" '{m=match($0,r,a)}m{print a[0]}' file
```

Otherwise I'd just use **anubhava**'s `grep -o` suggestion as it's shorter and clearer.